# How to update the value through event in the v-for in a vue -template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am new to Vue and laravel..

I am fetching data from **API Resource** in Laravel..

MY API contains 2fields

```
Goal
Value
```

This is my code

```
<template>
 <div class="container">
    <h1> Progress </h1>
       <div  class= "progress"  v-for = "progressdata in progress" v-bind:id="progressdata.id">
              <div>{{ progressdata.goal }}</div>
              <div id="div2">{{ progressdata.value }}</div>

        </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data: function() {
            return {
              progress: [],
              
           }
        },
 mounted() {
       this.loadContents();
       this.listen();
 },

methods: {
    loadContents: function() {

           //load Api
          
           axios.get('/api/progress')
           .then((response) => {
                this.progress = response.data.data;
               
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
    });
  },
    listen(){
      Echo.channel('progress')
          .listen('UpdatedValue', (e) =>{
            var target = e.target;
            console.log(target);
            var value = e.value;
            console.log(value);
            var div1 = document.getElementById(target);
            console.log(div1);
            div1.innerHTML = value;
            //console.log(e);

    });
    }
}
}
</script>
```

output :

```
54974 -- Goal
6543 --value(Updated through tinker)
2   --Goal
1    --Value
463 --Goal
52   --Value
```

The problem is when I triggered the event through tinker

```
event(new UpdatedValue('div2', 6543));
```

I could get the value updated to the particular DIv with the ID **div2**..

I want the entire **Value** in the array to be updated  in the v-for in the template, once I trigger the event through tinker with the target and the value.

I don't know how to proceed ..Could someone please help ?

thanks.

Comment: You should update `this.progress` in listen() to re-render. You should read Reactivity in Depth at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: sir, how could I update this.progress in listen() ..Could you please help?

Comment: What are you getting by listening to `UpdatedValue` Can't you use this to push or update the progress?

Comment: Will you ouput console.log(e) in your "listen('UpdatedValue', (e) =>"

Comment: @kurt Friars this is the output of console.log(e) : {value: 4764, target: "div2"} ,where in the tinker I used >>>event(new UpdatedValue('div2' ,4764));

Comment: @Saleem The UpdatedValue returns  {value: 4764, target: "div2"} ,after console.log(e)..I want the value to be binded once I trigger the value through event with the target(div's) and the value.. >>>event(new UpdatedValue('div2' ,4764));..Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the Event inside Echo:

```
listen(){
      Echo.channel('progress')
          .listen('UpdatedValue', (e) =>{

            let ToUpdate = this.progress.find(x => x.id === e.target)
            ToUpdate.value = e.value;
            //console.log(e);

    });
```

Comment: Sir, I could n't understand let ToUpdate = this.progress.find(x => x.id === e.target) ..Could you please explain? Thanks

Comment: Of course. 
That is an Array.Prototype.Find function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

It search inside the array of elements (this.progress) for the element that has an id equal to e.target and return the first element found (that is the element where you want to update the data). In this way, it stays reactive.

Comment: Sir , understood.But I need to bind the value to div's in the progress array(of size 4) , In the template I have  <div id="div2">{{ progressdata.value }}</div> , where it repeats 4 times with the different values. When I trigger the event through tinker >>event(new UpdatedValue('div2' ,224)); The value is updated only to the first div with the div id (div2)  ..I need to modify the other div's too ..since it is in v-for I could use only one div ..I want other div's too with the particular id..How could I do that sir,?

Comment: I just noticed an important thing. You are setting 
`<div id="div2">{{ progressdata.value }}</div>`
so you are adding id="div2" to all the elements in the v-for loop. This will result to an error, because the ID of an element has to be UNIQUE inside the DOM.

Comment: Yes sir, I want to set the div with the unique ID to all the div's inside the Progress array ..But they should hold the value from the API..Once I trigger the event the targeted div should change with the given value through the Tinker..How could I do that sir? Thanks.

Comment: So use something like: 

`<div :id="'div_'+progressdata.id">`
this will generate an unique ID for each element like : div_1, div_2, div_3 and so on..

Comment: Sir , I have tried the code listen(){
      Echo.channel('progress')
          .listen('UpdatedValue', (e) =>{
           let ToUpdate = this.progress.find(x => x.id === e.target);
            ToUpdate.value = e.value;
         }); and in the template                                                                                     
             <div :id="'div_'+progressdata.value"></div></div> But I received  Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at app.js:1956 error..How could I solve this? Could you please help sir? Could not bind the value to the div using tinker.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with Vue's reactivity, is that it wont trigger if you update nested properties. So if you were to find the progress item you wanted and updated its value, it would not be reflected until something forced it to re-render.

I think you should be able to do the following. By modifying the array the v-for is based on, you should get the reactivity you desire.

For the following solution to work, you need to be returning some identifying information in the listen event that is also available in the progress data item. Ideally, as in my following solution, the event returns an object with the same properties as whats in the progress array. As such,

```
listen(){
    Echo.channel('progress').listen('UpdatedValue', (e) => {
        const idx = this.progress.findIndex((item) => {
            return item.id = e.id;
        });
        
        if (idx < 0) {
            this.progress.push(e);
        } else {
            this.progress.splice(idx, 1, e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Progress</h1>
    <div class="progress" v-for="p in progress" :key="p.id">
      <div>{{ p.goal }}</div>
      <div>{{ p.value }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      progress: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadContents();
    this.listen();
  },
  methods: {
    loadContents: function() {
      axios
        .get('/api/progress')
        .then(response => (this.progress = response.data.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },
    listen() {
      Echo.channel('progress').listen('UpdatedValue', progress => {
        // console.log(this.progress, progress);
        this.progress = this.progress.map(p => {
          // You should have something common here. May be id or any other key that you can compare to find the element in the progress array
          if (p.id == progress.id) {
            p.value = progress.value;
          }
          return p;
        });
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

If it doesn't work, you can uncomment log line and let me know the result.

`<div id="div2" v-html="progressdata.value"></div>` can be changed with `<div>{{ progressdata.value }}</div>` if there is no html to update but just number.

Example on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-brook-p1euk?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: thank you sir. I implemented the code .I received error (Error in render: "TypeError: Cant read property 'id' of undefined") and after uncommenting the console.log I got(entire Progress array 0:
description: "Sunt quasi."
goal: 54974
name: "Quaerat voluptas."
the_custom_id: 1
value: 30789                                                                                                       :

Comment: After passing the value through tinker  event(new UpdatedValue('div2' ,224));                I got the below array. {value: 224, target: "div2"}
target: "div2"
value: 224
__proto__: Object

Comment: Also in this proposed solution:
`<div id="div2" v-html="progressdata.value"></div>` is inside a v-for. 
The rendered elements will all have div2 as ID and this is an error

Comment: What is the common in the progress and the e (payload) that you get on event. There must be something common that you can compare to find the element in the progress array. As I said you can uncomment the log line and let me know the log so that I can suggest.

Comment: event(new UpdatedValue('div2', 6543)); Can you pass the progress id instead of the `div2`?

Comment: The common thing is the value attribute which is in progress array. The value in the progress array should be updated once the event is triggered through tinker to the respective div's.

Comment: Could n't get you progress id? Could you please help ..Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-brook-p1euk?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: this is the log (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0:
description: "Sunt quasi cumque aut error non qui iste."
goal: 54974
name: "Quaerat voluptas."
the_custom_id: 1
value: 54046.                    {value: 88, target: "progress"}

Comment: Sure sir..I want the event to be triggered through tinker , where you are triggering through the button ..

Comment: Sir, could you please check the sandbox, Where I have updated id 1 to all buttons , so only 1st value will change the rest remains unchanged..

Comment: In my code the result looks like Name: 54974     Value: 565
Name: 2     Value: 565
Name: 463     Value: 565
Name: 538018966     Value: 565. when I tried >>event(new UpdatedValue(3, 565)); It s binding to all the div's not to the div with id =3 ..Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: @KomalRaja Yes, the listen is trigger with button. I am just trying to give you the logic and working example so that you can implement it. You can update the progress from any method or for any event. The logic should be same. Send the progress id with new value and update as the  listen method. I can't see any change to sandbox, if you have setup, please share the link.

Comment: @Saleem sir, Thanks a lot for your support ..It was really very helpful ..

Comment: @ Saleem sir , I want to implement a UI design similar to Speedometer , with 3 buttons run, pause and remove . where the idea is we have 2 fields Target(Goal) and a Value(from Server)..For ex if the goal is 1000 and the Server value is 600 ..1.When the user clicks the run button , the knob in the speedometer should run till  600  2. When  the user clicks pause button , for ex,  if he clicks in 590 it should pause a while and again should start running till 600 is reached. 3. If the user presses remove button the entire value should be removed ..Could you please tell me if you any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Saleem sir, Updated the code in sandbox , I have  tried a sample code with Vuetify component , but the plugin is not  imported I guess, I am getting few errors ..Could you please check sir..                                                         
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-grothendieck-lp1ij?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I am sorry as I never used `Vuetify ` https://www.vuemastery.com/ has nice courses to learn `Vuejs` and `Vuetify ` You can explore udemy.com too

Comment: @Saleem sir ,Thanks for your reply.. I want a UI similar to speedometer with laravel ..Could you please suggest me some ideas other than Vuetify , because Vuetify is not a requirement. Thanks.